# Is there a way to make List style insetGrouped in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

So let’s say for example that I have a list declared like this

```
List {
    Section {
        Text(“Test Row Title 1”)
    }
    Section {
        Text(“Test Row Title 2”)
    }
}
```

Is it possible to make the style of that the same as UITableView.Style.insetGrouped? I can’t find any information about that.
I thought that it would be as simple as `.listStyle(InsetGroupedStyle())`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently there is a new API in iOS/iPadOS 14 which finally allows InsetGrouped style to be in SwiftUI.

```
List {
  ...
}
.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
```

Comment: You can now just write `.listStyle(.insetGrouped)` :)

Answer (score 8):

In iOS 13.2, you can set `.environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)` on `.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())` to get the same style as `UITableView.Style.insetGrouped`.

```
List {
    Section {
        Text(“Test Row Title 1”)
    }
    Section {
        Text(“Test Row Title 2”)
    }
}.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
.environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)
```

https://sarunw.com/tips/inset-grouped-in-swiftui/

Comment: The only drawback I'm having here is when you're using a NavigationView and you navigate back to the view that is using this trick, the sections rounded corners are lost / square (you have to force a redraw someway to get the rounded corners back).

Answer (score 2):

My implementation is not ideal, but this is what I'm happy with for now.  I stared by creating a ViewModifier, CardViewModifier() that I use for creating an inset card view.  I use it in several places in my App, not just with the lists.

```
struct CardViewModifier: ViewModifier {

var backgroundColor = Color(.systemBackground)

func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color(.systemBackground))
        .cornerRadius(12)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

To "fake" an insetGrouped List, I convert the List to a ScrollView and the Sections to VStacks, like so.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let data = ["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3", "Row 4", "Row 5"]

    var body: some View {

        ScrollView {

            VStack {
                ForEach(data, id:\.self) { row in
                    VStack {
                        Text("Section 1, \(row)")
                        Divider()
                    }
                }
            }
            .modifier(CardViewModifier())

            VStack {
                ForEach(data, id:\.self) { row in
                    Text("Section 2, \(row)").padding()
                }
            }
            .modifier(CardViewModifier())
        }
        .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
    }
}
```

Like I said its not ideal, but it will work until Apple (or someone else) creates an InsetGroupedListStyle.  When that happens, it should be a simple case of changing the ScrollView back to a List and the VStacks back to Sections.

Good luck...

Answer (score 2):

You can add `.environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)` to your list.

Answer (score 1):

The below code may help you and give you a solution to custom your own view. Playing with `.cornerRadius` and `.padding` modifiers:

```
struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {

    VStack {

        List {

            Section {
                Text("Test Row Title 1")
            }
            Section {
                Text("Test Row Title 2")
            }
        }.cornerRadius(20)
        .padding()


        List {

            Section {
                Text("Test Row Title 3")
            }
            Section {
                Text("Test Row Title 4")
            }
        }.cornerRadius(20)
            .padding()


    }.background(Color.blue)
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, but it doest's work the same as insetGrouped on UITableView. I'm not sure what's the corner radius of the inset grouped view. Oh and also I guess there's no way to remove the separator in the List, right? I know that I can do `UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .clear` but that just looks ugly and doesn't seem native at all.

Comment: Yes you are right, It seems you have to make your own custom view. And yes for the separator that's the solution.